# Voice Typing stops abruptly

Tags: voice-recognition

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note 4. At some point in the last 6 months or so, voice typing just stopped working for longer than a couple of seconds of dictation.  It doesn't matter if I talk very fast with no pauses at all. It just stops abruptly. I have to keep hitting the microphone button repeatedly to get it to complete.

Where do I begin to start debugging this?